# Unable to Silent Execute the Command in WiX Script

Tags: wix

Below is my code when i try to install my MSI it does everything but the lines below shows no sign of execution.

```
                <Binary Id="unzipExeId" SourceFile="unzip.exe"/>
                <Property Id="WixQuietExec64CmdLine" Value="[#$(var.InstallationLocation)\unzip.exe]"/>
                <CustomAction Id="unzipAction" BinaryKey="unzipExeId" DllEntry="WixQuietExec64" Execute='deferred' Return ='asyncWait' Impersonate='no'/>
                <InstallExecuteSequence>
                    <Custom Action='unzipAction' Before='InstallFinalize'/>
                </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Did I miss anything.

But When i Try this code

```
                <Binary Id="unzipExeId" SourceFile="unzip.exe"/>
                <CustomAction Id="unzipAction" BinaryKey="unzipExeId" ExeCommand="START /B unzip.exe" Execute='deferred' Return ='asyncWait' Impersonate='no'/>
                <InstallExecuteSequence>
                    <Custom Action='unzipAction' Before='InstallFinalize'/>
                </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Everything Works Just Fine but the execution of the unzip.exe causes a pop up in the machine. The exe is not silently installed. But i need to silently execute the EXE.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be related to DllEntry instead of using "WixQuietExec64" try to use "CAWixQuietExec64".

There is an open issue regarding this.
http://wixtoolset.org/issues/4802/

This is as a common use:

```
<CustomAction Id="CA_RunBatchScript"
              BinaryKey="WixCA"
              DllEntry="CAQuietExec"
              Execute="deferred"
              Return="check" />
```

Comment: I used the DLLs CAQuietExec and CAWixQuietExec64. both on installing says  "There is a problem with this Windows Installer package A DLL required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor"

Comment: https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/standard-libraries/silence-please/ 

This is what i excatly did same as what you mentioned but still there exe is not triggered